# How to write data in ESP32-S2 internal ROM?

Tags: embedded, esp32, flash-memory, rom, usb-flash-drive

I'm working on a project that needs to write setting fast in the internal flash of ESP32-S2

My data size is 20 bytes

How can I do this work?

Comment: Read the data sheet, look for application notes, experiment.

Comment: ESP32 came with library and examples for [EEPROM](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/EEPROM) access.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE that is for ESP32 Company and I'm not using Arduino

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the flash memory in a few ways. NVS, SPIFFS, and FAT filesystems are all included in ESP-IDF. For storing basic settings that don't change often I'd use NVS. You can set up a csv with your initial values, flash it to your NVS partition, and access and change it later. All the methods are well documented by the company.
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/api-reference/storage/index.html

You can find examples of how to use it here:
https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/storage